# Android read external storage not working in Android Kitkat

Tags: android

I have the following code for reading a text file from storage:

```
//Get the text file
      File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"CONFIG.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Configuration file not found!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

This code is working fine in jellybean device(Micromax canvas4). But it is not reading from a kitkat device(Moto G).It is getting the toast message "Configuration file not found" I have tried a lot. But not working. How can I figure out??

Comment: did you changed the sdk level and compiling sdk level to 4.4.2?

Comment: @Jigar there is no such method

Comment: It's `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`.  But the docs say that's within `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, so that doesn't explain your problem.

Comment: Is there actually a SD card in the Moto G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding permissions READ and WRITE SD card!! Thanks guys for all support